# Routing trunking vlans to access vlans using same subnet

Tags: routes, cisco, vlan

i have a computer named (PC A) connected to this trunking vlan 100 which containing multiple subnets for example:

1. 60.60.x.x/16
2. 70.70.x.x/16
3. 80.80.x.x/16

I want to do some routing using this trunking vlan (VLAN 100) to access vlans (VLAN 200,300,400) using Cisco switches/routers which is connected to computers (PC B,C,D) on the other side:

- 60.60.x.x/16 (VLAN 200)
- 70.70.x.x/16 (VLAN 300)
- 80.80.x.x/16 (VLAN 400)

What is the best approach to route these subnets (FROM VLAN 100 to VLAN 200,300,400)

- if the VLAN number on both sides cannot be changed due to network infrastructure
- if the ip address on both sides computers cannot be changed due to security concerns

i am using cisco layer 3 switches to achieve this task. Please do not give suggestions like changing VLAN number and ip addresses.

Comment: Please use networkengineering.stackexchange.com as hinted at in the `cisco` tag.

Answer (score -1):

That won't work. You can't use the same IP network addresses on two different sides of a router. You could use a bridge but that may not be what you want.

You can route 60.60.0.0/16 destinations *over* a subnet using 70.70.0.0/16 (or anything) but the bound ports cannot reside in that subnet. If PC A requires local IPs from each 60.60.0.0/16, 70.70.0.0/16, and 80.80.0.0/16 subnet then you need to connect it with each VLAN you've set up to transport these subnets.

If you have a VLAN ID or IP address collision when connecting two network your best choice is renumbering. Working around the problem is possible but usually creates a mess that is hard to manage and may produce unexpected problems.

Comment: Thank you for the help.
 
I am trying to merge internal vlans(VLAN 200,300,400) at my user side on both ends into a common vlan(VLAN 100) which is a bridge to connect them together due to limitation number of vlans. So is it possible in this case?

Comment: If you bridge those VLANs they effectively become a single one. You should describe your goal because usually you divide your traffic into separate VLANs not bridge them together.